# How to block direct access to my custom 404 page in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, http-status-code-404

I am using Apache2 as web server in Ubuntu and my root is /var/www/html. In there I have an .htaccess file with

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /custom404.html
```

in it. This works. When I visit mydomain.com/arandomstring I see the custom404.html page. However, what I want to do is block direct access to custom404.html like domain.com/custom404.html should not work. How would I achieve this? I have searched StackOverflow extensively but found no help in this regard.

Comment: Have you tried LocationMatch on the error documents with a deny from all?  The ErrorDocument you have appears to be an internal redirect.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/970888/how-to-deny-direct-access-to-errordocument-in-apache-httpd#970913

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply block all access, since the custom error document needs to be accessible in order to be served.

However, you can block direct access by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is empty on the initial request and set to the HTTP status code when an error occurs (eg. "404" in the case of a 404 Not Found).

For example, using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^custom404\.html$ - [F]
```

This serves a 403 Forbidden when `/custom404.html` is requested directly. Or change `F` to `R=404` to serve a 404 Not Found instead (without triggering a rewrite loop).

**UPDATE:** If used in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context then you need a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example: `RewriteRule ^/custom404\.html$ - [F]`

> ```
>     <Location /custom404.html>
>        RewriteEngine On
>        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
>        RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
>     </Location>
> ```

It would be simpler (and marginally more efficient) to write it like this (code below) instead (the `<Location>` wrapper is not required):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
RewriteRule ^/custom404\.html$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Hi +MrWhite, thank you so much. I however forego my .htaccess file and instead put ErrorDocument 404 /custom404.html in my 000-default.conf file. Below that I put   <Location /custom404.html>
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
           RewriteRule .* - [F]
        </Location> . Would this be the same as what you wrote?

Comment: That's essentially the same. However, the `<Location>` wrapper is superfluous (as is the `.*` regex) - the URL check can be performed directly in the `RewriteRule` directive - as shown in my answer. This  would be more efficient. But note that if the directive is directly in the server config (outside of a _directory_ context) then you need a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. eg. `RewriteRule ^/custom404\.html$ - [F]`.

Comment: I think https://pastebin.com/uyGK9rN2 might help for you to see my .conf file. Is this correct? Specifically line 9 onwords -- <Location /custom404.html> .... +MrWhite

Comment: I've updated my answer addressing your code.

Comment: Thanks +MrWhite. I don't understand what your update means. Is my code current and needs to stay unchanged? Do I need to do RewriteRule ^/ or is RewriteRule .*  OK?

Comment: Yes, since you have defined a custom 404 `ErrorDocument` it will show your custom 404 page when you trigger a 404 response. But, importantly, the server sends a 404 HTTP status and not a 200 OK status as would happen if requesting the error document directly. What would the desired response be?

Comment: "I don't understand what your update means." - I'm saying that it would be simpler to write it like I have done in my answer. Like I say in my answer, the `<Location>` wrapper is not required.

Comment: I don't want to trigger the custom 404 page for domain.com/custom404.html but want to trigger default 404 for the same. How would I change my code in .conf file (pastebin) for that? Thus, like R=403 works but not R=404 as it takes to custom 404 page +MrWhite

Comment: I changed it to    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
        RewriteRule ^/custom404\.html$ - [R=404] without <location> wrapper. Now when I go on domain.com/custom404.html I don't see default 404 page but see custom one. How to show default ?

Comment: Isn't that a bit odd? Why not serve the same 404 response? By serving a different 404 response you are alerting the user-agent that there is something different about the request.

Comment: Then what was the "without triggering a rewrite loop" for. What did you mean by that? +MrWhite

Comment: Because without the _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var you will get a rewrite loop (500 response) as the `/custom404.html` will repeatedly trigger a 404 when the error document itself is called by the internal subrequest.

Comment: Oh ok. So that "without triggering a rewrite loop" did not mean it would trigger the default plain looking 404 page? +MrWhite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226502/discussion-between-karatin-and-mrwhite).